# Get the list of user groups with Facebook API

Tags: facebook, api

I'm trying to get a list of the user's Facebook groups.
To do this, I analyze the documentation to understand it (Graph API) :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/user/groups

However, when I use this query, I get no results

I've done a lot of research.
And from what I understand, it is no longer possible today to obtain the list of user groups (depeacrated)

However, I do not understand. The documentation page still exists, for version 3.2 ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/user/groups) and nothing says that this is no longer possible.

Documentation says :

> Returns a list of Groups where the User is a member and the User has granted the app any Group-level permissions for that Group "

My code :

```
FB.api(
    "/" + id + "/groups",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    }
);
```

I would like to get a list of all the user's groups, not just the groups where he is an admin.

Comment: the docs may not be up to date, afaik it is not possible anymore to get all groups.

Comment: For 4 years, they would have had time to specify it on the documentation?
This is very strange.

Comment: It´s already 4 years? Well, not sure, but everything is possible ;)

Comment: What 4 years are you talking about? I don’t see what would be out of date here, you quoted above the conditions under which you can get what kind of user groups, and on the very top of the page it also says, _“As of April 4, 2018, this edge returns empty data sets for GET operations unless the calling app has gone through App Review. This applies to GET operations using /me/groups as well.”_, which most likely explains your “no results” as well.

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/groups/

admin_only=true

pass this parameter you will get only list of those groups where you are admin.

Comment: This document refers to a feature that was removed after Graph API v3.2.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the groups, when askd for `groups_access_member_info` permission during the facbook-login process, but it asks too much: with this permission app can post in your groups as well and can read former posts. I guess nobody will give you this rights, it seems this feature is over.

Additionally: in my privacy settings i found that the list of my groups are private information (haven't set is explicitly .. at least i dont remember) so it's maybe practically deprecated because of this default setting.